# Does kendo UI use bundled jQuery?

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET Core 2.2 application that is using `jQuery v3.3.1`.

The application is also configured to use Telerik's Kendo UI version `v2016.3.1007` . The Kendo UI library is based on jQuery. All Kendo UI bundles include the corresponding minified jQuery library in the js directory. The kendo version i am using is bundled with jQuery version `v1.12.3`

[image]

I would like to use jQuery v3.3.1 in my application for all other DOM manipulation and Kendo UI keep using jQuery v1.12.3.

In _layout.cshtml i have

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

**Questions**
1> Does kendo UI use the bundled jQuery or the jQuery that is referenced in `_layout.cshtml`?

2>If kendo UI is using bundled jQuery then why Kendo's documentation says

> In order for the Kendo UI scripts to work as expected, make sure you
>   include a reference to the jQuery library in the document before the
>   scripts

2>As per [Kendo's jQuery prerequisite](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites) the version `v2016.3.1007` also compatible with  2.2.x but not with `3.*`. What are my options here to use jQuery 3.* (*other than upgrading Kendo UI :)*)

Comment: Using jquery-migrate should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41364970/4825632

Comment: Kendo jquery version info: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites